# Delay then fire a new page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a standard navigation with a href links, when the user clicks these I want this to fire after 1 second, as I want to do an animation before directing them to the new page.

I can delay then fire the user to the page, but this is only hard coding in the direction, but there will be lots of links.

```
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/health-and-care/" class="introduction">Introduction</a></li>
                <li><a href="/health-and-care/agenda" class="agenda">Speakers, Agenda & Venue</a></li>
                <li><a href="/health-and-care/about" class="about">About InterSystems</a></li>
                <li class="nolive"><a href="#" class="register-nav"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-check"></i> Register</a></li>
            </ul>
```

jQuery

```
    $('a').click (function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       setTimeout(function () {
           window.location.href = "blog.html";
        }, 2000);

    });
```

Comment: Isn't the code working? What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: What do you mean by "hard coding in the direction"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to location `dynamically` like this :

```js
$('a').click (function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   let url = $(this).attr('href');
   setTimeout(function () {
       window.location.href = url;
    }, 2000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/health-and-care/" class="introduction">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="/health-and-care/agenda" class="agenda">Speakers, Agenda & Venue</a></li>
    <li><a href="/health-and-care/about" class="about">About InterSystems</a></li>
    <li class="nolive"><a href="#" class="register-nav"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-check"></i> Register</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Ivan!!